# Making 1 page pdfs from a multipage pdf using itextsharp

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext

I have a pdf that I want to make into several 1 page pdfs where each page in the original pdf is now its own pdf document. I am trying to do this using itextsharp, but am having some difficulty even getting started.

Am I going about this the wrong way? Anyone know how I would go about doing this?

Thanks a ton!

Comment: Can't remember the code off the top of my head, but but was n't much when I did it. I'll post it tomorrow if no one else does.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Thanks that would be much appreciated. I think I might have worked it out before I left, but had to leave in a bit of a hurry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(argPdfFileName, FileMode.Create))
{
  Document doc = new Document(argReader.GetPageSize(argPdfPageNumber));
  PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(doc, fs);
  doc.Open();
  PdfImportedPage page = copy.GetImportedPage(argReader, argPdfPageNumber);
  copy.AddPage(page);
  doc.Close();
}
```

Chopped this out of some working code.
argReader is a PdfReader instance pointing at the source document. argPdfPageNumber is the pagenumber in question.
Basically you just create a new pdf. Import the source page into it and then add it to the document and save.

Answer (score 1):

There is a different library, [PDFSharp](http://www.pdfsharp.net/), that may be better suited for this.  You can open a PDFDocument object, and go through each page individually, extracting it into is own, separate PDF document.

Answer (score 1):

There are two different commandline tools which can do that, both for any of the major OS platforms available.

### pdftk

Example commandline:

```
pdftk input.pdf burst output page_%04d-from-input.pdf
```

### Ghostscript

Example commandline:

```
gs \
   -o page_%04d-from-input.pdf \
   -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
    input.pdf
```

**Caveats:** It's only the most recent version of Ghostscript which supports this commandline syntax of `%04d` for page-wise different output files + names.

`pdftk` isn't able to do any PDF manipulation in the process and is very fast.

The new Ghostscript method somewhat slower, but has the advantage that it can apply a lot of its other PDF processing capabilities should you need them.

Comment: Thank you for this post. Please forgive my naivety as I am fairly new to .NET, but would I be able to incorporate these scripts to my site?

Comment: Ah... I only now get aware of your [itextsharp] tag. So you want to do this programmatically... I'm pretty sure that you can call an 'external' commandline from itextsharp too, but you may prefer to use a lib there too. Just like @NYSystemAnalyst suggested...